# C++ OpenGL Large Mesh is missing triangles

Tags: c++, arrays, opengl, vbo, heightmap

So I'm putting together a height map renderer that will do most of the work int he vertex shader, but first of course I generate a mesh to render, at the moment I'm playing around with upper limits of openGL and C++ to see how dense a mesh I can render (so I later have something to go by in terms of LoD mesh dividing)

**ANYWAY!** to cut to the issue;

the issue I noticed after testing a meshResolution of 32, 64 and at 128 I experienced runtime crashes, I stopped them by using the a self made class "indexFace" which holds 6 indices to lower the array length, problem is at 128 resolution only a 3rd of the mesh actually displays, I was wondering if there was a limit to how many indices openGL can render or hold using 1 set of BufferObjects or if its an issue with my handling of the C++ side of things.

I'm generating the mesh via the following:

```
void HeightMapMesh::GenerateMesh(GLfloat meshScale, GLushort meshResolution)
{
    GLushort vertexCount = (meshResolution + 1) * (meshResolution + 1);
    Vertex_Texture* vertexData = new Vertex_Texture[vertexCount];
    GLushort indexCount = (meshResolution * meshResolution) * 6;

//indexFace holds 6 GLushort's in an attempt to overcome the array size limit
    indexFace* indexData = new indexFace[meshResolution * meshResolution];
    GLfloat scalar = meshScale / ((GLfloat)meshResolution);
    GLfloat posX = 0;
    GLfloat posY = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x <= meshResolution; x++)
    {
        posX = ((GLfloat)x) * scalar;
        for (int y = 0; y <= meshResolution; y++)
        {
            posY = ((GLfloat)y) * scalar;
            vertexData[y + (x * (meshResolution + 1))] = Vertex_Texture(posX, posY, 0.0f, x, y);
        }
    }
    GLint indexPosition;
    GLint TL, TR, BL, BR;
    for (int x = 0; x < meshResolution; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < meshResolution; y++)
        {
            indexPosition = (y + (x * (meshResolution)));
            BL = y + (x * (meshResolution + 1));
            TL = y + 1 + (x * (meshResolution + 1));
            BR = y + ((x + 1) * (meshResolution + 1));
            TR = y + 1 + ((x + 1) * (meshResolution + 1));
            indexData[indexPosition] = indexFace(
                    BL, TR, TL,
                    BL, BR, TR
                    );
        }
    }
    mesh.Fill(vertexData, vertexCount, (void *)indexData, indexCount, GL_STATIC_DRAW, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    delete [] vertexData;
    delete [] indexData;
}

//This is for mesh.Fill()
    void Fill(T* vertData, GLushort vertCount, void* indData, GLushort indCount, GLenum vertUsage, GLenum indUsage)
    {
        indexCount = indCount;
        vertexCount = vertCount;
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBufferObjectID);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBufferObjectID);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(T) * vertexCount, vertData, vertUsage);
        glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLushort) * indexCount, indData, indUsage);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its because you made your indices shorts.

For example this: `GLushort indexCount = (meshResolution * meshResolution) * 6;` is hitting USHRT_MAX at a value of 105 for `meshResolution`. (105*105*6 = 66150 > 65535)

Use ints as indices. So change your indices everywhere to unsigned ints and do the final draw call like this:

```
glDrawElements( GL_QUADS, indCount, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, indices); //do this
//glDrawElements( GL_QUADS, indCount, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, indices); //instead of this
//also GL_QUADS is deprecated but it seems your data is in that format so I left it that way
```

You could save a bunch of indices if you drew `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP`s instead or better yet do tesselation on the GPU, since this is like the perfect use-case for it.

Comment: slight correction, while ushort and uint were my issue it was because I was using ushort to pass around the index count, the vertices was still well within the ushort limit so it was safe to keep the indices as ushorts, thanks for the help though for some reason I was confusing shorts limits with ints and ints with longs.
GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP I'll be looking up its order always confused me when you have multiple rows, but research makes perfect I guess, thanks again.